# How should I make a URL router?

Tags: backend

My question is how are url routers made and by routers I mean instead of people accessing my scripts from https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.py they could access it for example from the url https://www.example.com/something/otherthing/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a web server configuration item.

In Apache, you would use a ScriptAlias command in the server's configuration file.

```
<Location "/cgi-bin">
    ScriptAlias "/something/otherthing/"
</Location>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias